# Add user to local database after registration in Stormpath

Tags: asp.net-core, stormpath

I want to add new user to my local database after register in Stormpath. In doc  https://docs.stormpath.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/latest/registration.html#registration is section about post-registration handler. I have problem becouse i can't use UserRepository in StartUp file. 
I have error:

> Unable to resolve service for type
>   'AppProject.Repositories.IUserRepository' while attempting to
>   activate 'AppProject.Startup'

---

.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IUserRepository userRepository)
            {
    services.AddStormpath(new StormpathOptions()
               {
                Configuration = new StormpathConfiguration()
                {
                    Client = new ClientConfiguration()
                    {
                        ApiKey = new ClientApiKeyConfiguration()
                        {
                            Id = "xxxxxxxxxxx",
                            Secret = "xxxxxxxxx"
                        }
                    }
                },
                PostRegistrationHandler = (context, ct) =>
               {
                   return MyPostRegistrationHandler(context, ct, userRepository);
               }
            });
}



   private Task MyPostRegistrationHandler(PostRegistrationContext context, CancellationToken ct, IUserRepository userRepository)
        {
            userRepository.Add(new User(context.Account.Email, context.Account.FullName, context.Account.GivenName, context.Account.Surname, context.Account.Username));
            userRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
```

Comment: An important reminder that Stormpath is shutting down August 17, 2017 at noon PST.  If you haven't already, please begin migrating off and onto another service.   I recommend Okta's developer platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario, I don't think it can resolve dependency of IUserRepository in StartUp. You can try something like this.

1) Add an extension method.

```
public static IServiceProvider AddServices(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
    // rest of the things.
    return services.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

2) Get the userRepository instance like like this.

```
   IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
   services.AddServices();
   var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
   var userRepository = provider.GetRequiredService<IUserRepository>();
```

ConfigurationServices will not have IUserRepository input parameter.